# AutoMapper Map If Not Null, Otherwise Custom Convert

Tags: c#, automapper

Here's my code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Foo2>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Bar, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bar == null ? new BarViewModel() : src.Bar))
```

Basically, "BarViewModel" has a parameterless ctor which sets up properties in the class.

So i'm trying to say to AutoMapper:

> If the value is null, then use the ctor for the class. otherwise use the mapping you have in place

The above is giving me a C# compiler error. And i'm guessing a cast wouldn't work either.

So is there a AutoMapper trick to do this?

Worst case i could remove that mapping for that property, and just do:

```
var mapped = Mapper.Map<Foo,Foo2>(src);
if (mapped.Bar == null) mapped.Bar = new BarViewModel();
```

But that's a tad ugly.

Ideas?

Comment: What is the compiler error, and why do you think a cast wouldn't work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [custom value resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers). The following should work:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Foo2>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Bar, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Bar == null ? new Bar() : Mapper.Map<Bar,Bar2>(src.Bar)))
```

Comment: `ResolveUsing()` doesn't exist in Automapper 8, so this answer is a bit outdated

Answer (score 10):

Now you can use `.NullSubstitute()` to replace NULL value to some custom value in Automapper, e.g.:

```
CreateMap<SMModel, VM_SMModel>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.myDate, o => o.NullSubstitute(new DateTime(2017,12,12)));
```

Comment: The only potential problem with this is it requires you to supply the source type to map from. If you're mapping a complex type, you may be in a situation where you need to create the final type/instance and you may even need the source to be able to do it.

Answer (score 9):

As of Automapper 8, `ResolveUsing` [is no longer an option](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing) but inline `Func`'s, `IValueResolver` and `IMemberValueResolver` are .

**Inline Func Example**

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
  cfg.CreateMap<Foo, FooViewModel>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.BarViewModel,
       opt  => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) =>
       {
         if (src.Bar == null)
           return new BarViewModel ();

           return Mapper.Map<Bar, BarViewModel>(src.Bar);
        }));

  cfg.CreateMap<Bar, BarViewModel>();
});
```

**IMemberValueResolver Example**

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, FooViewModel>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.BarViewModel,
                  opt  => opt.MapFrom<NullBarResolver, Bar>(src => src.Bar));

    cfg.CreateMap<Bar, BarViewModel>();
});

public class NullBarResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, Bar, BarViewModel>
{
    public BarViewModel Resolve(object source, object destination, Bar sourceMember,
                                BarViewModel destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (sourceMember == null)
            return new BarViewModel();

        return Mapper.Map(sourceMember, destMember);
    }
}
```

---

There's some good documentation on [Custom Value Resolvers here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html).

[Working demo](https://github.com/spottedmahn/Experiments/tree/master/Automapper%20Expirements/Customer%20Value%20Resolvers%20Attempt%202)

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with the `PreCondition()` method. Here's an extension method I wrote to do this more easily:

```cs
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapIf<TSource, TDestination>(
        this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map, Expression<Func<TDestination, object>> selector,
        Func<TSource, bool> mapIfCondition, Expression<Func<TSource, object>> mapping)
    {
        map.ForMember(selector, c =>
        {
            c.MapFrom(mapping);
            c.PreCondition(mapIfCondition);
        });
        return map;
    }
```

Usage Example:

```
//if settings are null coming from the sender, then ignore them and keep the current settings
CreateMap<PresentationView, Presentation>()
   .MapIf(x => x.Settings, x => x.Settings is not null, v => v.Settings!)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't get a compiler error for the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo2
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Bar()
    {
        Id = 3;
    }
}

CreateMap<Foo, Foo2>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Bar,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bar == null ? new Bar() : src.Bar));
```

...so I'm wondering if the problem is not actually with your mapping?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does `BarViewModel` inherit from `Bar`? If yes, then I think a cast *would* work, and you wouldn't need a ValueResolver. But I guess you tried that already?

Comment: nope, no inheritance. the accepted answer was the right solution.