# Automapper complex object mapping NullReference exception

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-3

I have the following classes

```
public class Group 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupTier> Tiers { get; set; }
}

public class GroupTier : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int Tier { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to map to the following ViewModel

```
public class GroupViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<decimal> Tiers { get; set; }
}
```

using the configuration

```
configuration.CreateMap<Group, GroupViewModel>()
   .ForMember(m => m.Tiers, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.Tiers.OrderBy(q => q.Tier).Select(q => q.Amount)));
```

I am using EF6 to query from the database. I am having trouble when the `Group.Tiers` is null. How can I handle the null value?

When I use the this configuration

```
configuration.CreateMap<Group, GroupViewModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Tiers, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.Tiers == null ? new List<decimal>() : u.Tiers.OrderBy(q => q.Tier).Select(q => q.Amount)));
```

I am getting this error

> Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'

Comment: Try use [link](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: what do you mean by use link?

Comment: You may want to try this question/answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555721/automapper-map-if-not-null-otherwise-custom-convert

Comment: @Saanch you clicked on link? it's a framework to map your objects to objects(AutoMaper)

Comment: What version of AutoMapper are you using? And are you using the LINQ projection?

Comment: Why not just initialize `Tiers` as an empty collection (e.g. HashSet) in `Group`'s constructor? That's a pretty common approach.

Comment: @JimmyBogard I am using `Projection` to fetch the data.

Comment: @DanielMelo I know what is `AutoMapper` @Jimmy Bogard is the author of this framework. Read my question properly before polluting the comment section with unconstructive comments.

Comment: @JimmyBogard I am using version `3.2.1`

Comment: @Saanch, sorry dude I thought you were using another form of mapping. I noticed that the object names are incorrect. Can not be? (GroupModel to GroupViewModel)

Comment: @DanielMelo ggod catch :)

Comment: What is the `Tier` type that you reference in your `OrderBy` on the `Tiers` property of the group? You didn't include it in your question and i think that the problem lives here

Comment: @samy Check the `GroupTier` class `Tier` is an `int` field

Comment: Indeed, i must have missed it while copy/pasting the problem

Comment: I cannot replicate the error using the code you posted (albeit i remove the EF IEntity interface). Could you post the whole stack trace of the error?