# How can I do null checks within a lambda expression while using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a mapping profile that looks like this:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile {

   public MappingProfile()
   {
       // DTO Mapping
       CreateMap<Animal, AnimalDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ReceivalDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Receival.ReceivalDate));    
   }
}
```

Now the issue here is I have a `Receival` as part of the `Animal` class which can be `null` at times. However, if I try any of the following I get error:

```
src.Receival != null ? src.Receival.ReceivalDate : null
```

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IValueResolver<Animal, AnimalDto, object>' because it is not a delegate type

```
src?.Receival.ReceivalDate
```

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

Now my question is how can I do null checks withing a lambda expression while using MappingProfiles?

Comment: One option is custom value resolver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555721/automapper-map-if-not-null-otherwise-custom-convert

Comment: Those null checks are built in. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: `src?.Receival.ReceivalDate` checks if src is null. You would rather like something like `src.Receival?.ReceivalDate` however the two comments before really solve your problem, I just wanted to ensure that you get this syntax correctly :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comment from @zaitsman helped, however, the solution I ended up going with was:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ReceivalDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (src.Receival != null) ? src.Receival.ReceivalDate : (DateTime?) null))
```

There reason this worked is because `null` cannot be used for the Lambda Expression; however, `(DateTime?) null` did.

Comment: It is only a lambda that is to be turned into an _expression tree_ that is not allowed to contain the `?.`. A "normal" lambda that is just turned into a delegate instance is OK. In other words, it is OK to say `Func<object, int?> f = x => x?.GetHashCode();`, but attempting `Expression<Func<object, int?>> e = x => x?.GetHashCode();` gives the compile-time error: `An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.`

Comment: Again, the code is useless, AM does the null check. by default.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Maybe the issue I was experiencing wasn't clear. It's not that it didn't work, but instead that it was smelly code.

Comment: The code above is useless, so I have no idea what you're saying.